# String argument in a method doesn't working

Tags: java, android

```
final EditText d1n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.d1n);
```

AA coming from edittext.

```
NotHesapla(d1n.getText().toString());
```

returns -1. if I try to

```
NotHesapla("AA");
```

working succesfully.

```
public double NotHesapla(String not) {
    double puan;
    if (not == "AA") { puan = 4; }
    else if (not == "BA") { puan = 3.5; }
    else if (not == "BB") { puan = 3; }
    else if (not == "CB") { puan = 2.5; }
    else if (not == "CC") { puan = 2; }
    else if (not == "DC") { puan = 1.5; }
    else if (not == "DD") { puan = 1; }
    else if (not == "FD") { puan = 0.5; }
    else if (not == "FF") { puan = 0; }
    else { puan = -1; }
    return puan;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo, don't compare String values using `==` !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Use `equals()`.

Comment: When using == with String you are comparing references. Not the actual text. Use equals()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare strings you need to use `equals()`:

```
if( not.equals("BA") )...
```

or better (to avoid NPE):

```
if( "BA".equals(not) )...
```

Comment: yes this is working. thank you. First time with this issue. I won't forget after this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `equals` method instead of `==` opertaor.

```
if (not.equals("AA")) { puan = 4; }
```

Note that:

```
== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For Strings always use the `equals` method !

```
public double NotHesapla(String not) {
double puan;
if ("AA".equals(not)) { puan = 4; }
else if ("BA".equals(not)) { puan = 3.5; }
else if ("BB".equals(not)) { puan = 3; }
else if ("CB".equals(not)) { puan = 2.5; }
else if ("CC".equals(not)) { puan = 2; }
else if ("DC".equals(not)) { puan = 1.5; }
else if ("DD".equals(not)) { puan = 1; }
else if ("FD".equals(not)) { puan = 0.5; }
else if ("FF") { puan = 0; }
else { puan = -1; }
return puan;}
```